# Wpf parent child relationship

Tags: wpf, grid

So i need to know that if a wpf window has got say 3 grids and we have a user control that we can drag. So when i drag it over the grids. Does the parent/child relationship changes every time i drag it over different grid?

Answer (score 1):

I would say no, however that depends on your Drag/Drop implementation

Usually when dragging an item, you're actually just dragging a placeholder of that item in the Adorner Layer. The actual item may or may not get removed from the original parent. The item doesn't actually get added to the new parent until you release the mouse and the Drop method occurs.

When I implemented some custom drag/drop in the past, the item got removed from the parent control on Drag, and on Drop it got added to a new parent (either a valid drop target, or back to the original parent)

Comment: Could you suggest a way i divide my window area into top, bottom, left, right and center fill, and when i drag and drop my user control over that area it returns top-b-l-r-c s values. I actually want to use the values for my docking class.

Comment: @user1082048 Your best bet is to use a `DockPanel` containing an element docked to top, bottom, left, right, and undocked (fill remaining space), and when an object gets dragged over those elements, do something based on the `DockPanel.Dock` property of the element.